# Move table row from one table to another using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to move a row from one table into another and back again.

I have this working going to the first table but the going back event is not firing. Here is my code

html

```
<table id="table_source">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><img src='move_image_path' alt='Move' class='move-row' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Another Row</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><img src='move_image_path' alt='Move' class='move-row' /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
   <table id="table_dest" class="active"><a href="#">People</a>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
          </tr>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Jquery

```
  $("#table_source img.move-row").click(function (e) {            
             var tr = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone();
             tr.find("img.move-row")
        .attr("src", "remove_image_path.jpg")
        .attr("alt", "Remove");
             $("#table_dest tbody").append(tr);
         });

         $("#table_dest img.move-row").click(function (e) {
             alert("hi") //THIS IS NOT FIRING
             var tr = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone();
             tr.find("img.move-row")
        .attr("src", "move_image_path.jpg")
        .attr("alt", "Move");
             $("#table_source tbody").append(tr);
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jQuery callback.

```
 $("#table_dest").on('click', 'img.move-row', function (e) {
     alert("hi") //THIS IS NOT FIRING
     var tr = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone();
     tr.find("img.move-row")
         .attr("src", "move_image_path.jpg")
         .attr("alt", "Move");
     $("#table_source tbody").append(tr);
 });
```

Initially, when the page loads the click events are binded to the existing images. The ones that are added dinamically don't have the event attached to them. By using the `on()`, you stop having this issue.